# Tail the most recent file

Tags: linux, bash, tail

I have a program that logs its output to an *.out file when running.  I set up a bash script to run several different times, so each run writes to a different *.out file.  I found that I could `tail` the most recent *.out file like this:

```
watch tail $(ls -tr *.out | tail -n1)
```

The problem seems to be that the referencing `$()` only gets executed once.  So when the first run finishes, `watch` continues to `tail` the same *.out file, even though there is now a newer *.out file.

How can I alter this to go to the next *.out file after one run finishes?

I tried doing some nesting of quotes and parentheses, but I don't really understand the details of referencing.  Matters are complicated by the fact that `watch` passes its command to `sh`, even though I'm using bash.

Bonus points:  it would be great if this could be modified to `tail -f` instead of just repeating `watch` every `n` seconds.

Comment: hm..I really don't understand the use case. Do you want to read a few files in real time? if yes, it's easier to use `tail -f *.out`

Comment: I generally agree with @pivanchy, although it's worth mentioning that POSIX `tail` isn't guaranteed to handle more than one file at a time.

Comment: @pivanchy that is the solution.  I did not realize it was that simple.

Comment: @JeffIrwin As long as you don't actually create new files, as I happily assumed.

Comment: @pivanchy  I am creating new files.  Sorry, I'll have to redact my earlier comment.  My test case was over-writing the same files again, but if I remove them and start again, `tail -f *.out` does not work.

Comment: @JeffIrwin It's not as bash will glob only all current files.

Comment: @JeffIrwin, you mean that you need to run a command once, but you'll remove-create a new files on that time(when a command is still on progress)?

Comment: @pivanchy  steffen got the right answer.  My program is creating new *.out files (after I start the tail/watch command) and I need it to update to the new file.  The problem that I'm using this for takes about 30 minutes per *.out file.  Instead of waiting that long, I used a smaller problem as a test case.  I forgot to remove the old logs between tests, so your specious solution seemed correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also dealt with this problem and finally came to this solution:

```
 watch "ls -t1 | sed q | xargs tail"
```

Need to get a bit hacky for the bonus. The `tail` command also supports an argument `--pid` which makes `tail` die as soon as the referenced PID dies. Sounds good? Here's some pattern you could use:

```
while true; do ls -t1 | sed q | xargs lsof -F np | sed 's/.\(.*\)/\1/g' | xargs tail -f --pid 2>/dev/null ; done
```

This basically tracks the most current file and restarts `tail` when the file writing process ends.

Comment: Thanks!  I just had to add a simple file filter like this:  `watch ls -t1 *.out | sed q | xargs tail"`

Comment: @JeffIrwin Also try out the edit. It's not watching the file any more but following the output directly (with tail).

Comment: The edit works great!  I'm not even going to try to understand all the pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

If all the files exist to begin with, and you have a modern implementation of `tail` that can handle multiple files,

```
tail -f *.out
```

would seem to be the best solution. But if you don't have all the files to begin with, then it would still be easiest if you just created them. `*.out` will expand only to the files you already have.

But if you can't know the filenames for `tail -f` before you start, then you will need to restart tail if any new outfiles are created while you are tailing. In that case, given you are only writing to each outfile one at a time, you could do:

```
inotifywait -m -e create -q . | while read dir event file; do
    kill %tail
    tail -f "$file" &
done
kill %tail
```

(The above requires `inotifywait`, which is included in `inotify-tools` on Debian-based systems like Ubuntu.) It watches the current directory for newly created files, tails whichever file was created, in the background, and kills the previous tail command whenever a new file is created.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'll duplicate a little my current answer:
[Tail the most recent file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957817/tail-the-most-recent-file#comment57647412_34957817)

you could use very simple command to resolve your issue:

```
tail -f *.out
```

tail works with a multiple files too and it's possible to use it like:

```
tail -f file1 file2 file3
```

So, as you can see, it's very powerful and easy tool and you don't need to play with linux commands

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem that the `*` is evaluated by the shell and thus any files which are created after tail is initially run will never be tailed.